# C# streams character encoding AND output from console

Tags: c#, character-encoding, stream

So I'm creating a program that can read the output from the windows command prompt. It works as seen here:

```
Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;


        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_OutputDataReceived);
        process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_ErrorDataReceived);
```

In the eventhandler I network the output. (server is also written in C# using streams)

```
static void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {
            socketInput.WriteLine(e.Data);
            socketInput.Flush();
        }
    }
```

This works almost completely fine except that some special characters (like swedish characters) prints out as gibberish on the server side. I have tried just `Console.WriteLine(e.Data)` on the client side and that seem to work so I think it has to do with my encoding on the networking part. Could someone explain to me the problem here? I have tried to figure out which encoding to use but haven't had any luck.

BTW. Here are the socket streams (they are similar on the server-side)

```
socketInput = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
socketOutput = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
```

Socket Init Client Side:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

        //retry connection until found
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 4444);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle errors
                continue;
            }
            if (client.Connected) break;

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
```

Socket Init Server Side:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 4444);
        listener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

Recieving code (run in separate thread):

```
while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(socketOutput.ReadLine());
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection lost!");
                return;
            }

        }
```

Comment: "prints out as gibberish on the server side." - show the actual socket init and receiving code, please. It is possible you are sending the console text wrong... but it might just as well be that you're simply handling the received data the wrong way. What is done after you receive the data? How do you save/display/check it?

Comment: updated the post with more details

Comment: You're printing it to the console. The streams you use all default to UTF-8, but the console can't handle UTF-8. That's your problem. If you output to a message box or a form it should display correctly.

Comment: Well since I'm originally taking the output from CMD I should be able to output it in my own console right? Now the remaining question is what encoding the CMD output utilises so I can use the same encoding for my streams.

Comment: `Encoding.Default` should give you the standard Windows encoding used by the machine.

Comment: Then why doesn't the code posted above work properly with encoding?? Isn't it already using the default encoding?

Comment: As I commented before... `the streams you use all default to UTF-8`. Defaulting to the PC's ansi encoding is a fairly bad idea for network things, since it can be different on different PCs. But, to be honest, I have no idea how you would need to output stuff to the console in a certain encoding... you'd have to research that yourself.